# ParallelTable and NC polynomial simplification

Tags: parallelization, rule, algebra, ncalgebra

I use NC algebra to apply simplification rules on non commutative polynomials.
I would like to treat a huge number of polynomials, ~200, so I would like to run these computations in parallel.

However, although Table works perfectly well, ParallelTable yields an error :
*$RecursionLimit::reclim :  Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. error*

A minimum example would be:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`;
Reduc[pol_, rul_] := 
  Module[{poln = NCReplaceRepeated[NCExpand[pol], rul]}, 
   If[SameQ[pol, poln], pol, Reduc[poln, rul]]];
xvars = {x1, x2};
yvars = {y1, y2};
evars = {e1, e2};
fvars = {f1, f2};

vars = {x1, x2, y1, y2};
gpvars = {e1, e2, f1, f2};
SetNonCommutative @@ vars
SetNonCommutative @@ gpvars
sub = { x1 -> (1 + e1)/2, y2 -> (1 + f2)/2};
ListTest = {x1, y2};
Table[Reduc[ListTest[[ii]], sub], {ii, 1, 2}]
ParallelTable[Reduc[ListTest[[ii]], sub], {ii, 1, 2}]
```

I can't understand why ; the variables x1 and y2 seem to me to be independant.Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess why it is not working it is because Mathematica is being smart about your comparison and fails to stop the recursion. I would however suggest that you use `NCExpandReplaceRepeated` instead, which I suppose does exactly what you want and does not break `ParallelTable`. You command becomes simply:

```
ParallelTable[NCExpandReplaceRepeated[ListTest[[ii]], sub], {ii, 1, 2}]
```